# Getting/Transfering Data out of a while (or any) loop in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, storage

i have this 2 related learning question:

1: How can I transfer data that was created within a loop (in my case a while loop) out of that loop and store it.
2: how can I replay the loop several times, and updating the data, with the new input from the loop, to the data that was stored outside the loop.

For that purpose I have this simple and (I know inelegant) code of dice roll game:

```
import random

player_input = input("how many rounds? ")





def main():
    roll1 = 0
    roll2 = 0 
    rounds = 1
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0 
    six = 0
    seven = 0
    eight = 0
    nine = 0
    ten = 0
    eleven = 0
    twelve = 0
    list1 = []
    listfinal = []


    while rounds <= int(player_input):
        roll1 = dice_roll()
        roll2 = dice_roll()
        third = roll1 + roll2
        
        
        
        
        if third == 2:
            two = two + 1
            
        
        if third == 3:
            three = three + 1
            
        
        if third == 4:
            four = four + 1
    
        
        if third == 5:
            five = five + 1
        
        if third == 6:
            six = six + 1
         
        if third == 7:
            seven = seven + 1        
        
        if third == 8:
            eight = eight + 1
            
        if third == 9:
            nine = nine + 1
            
        if third == 10:
            ten = ten + 1
            
        if third == 11:
            eleven = eleven + 1
            
        if third == 12:
            twelve = twelve + 1
            
        rounds = rounds + 1
    print("two =", + two, " three=", + three, " four=", + four, " five=", + five, " six=", + six, " seven=", + seven,
              " eight=", + eight, " nine=", + nine, " ten=", + ten, " eleven=", + eleven, " twelve=", + twelve)

    list1.append(two)
    list1.append(three)
    list1.append(four)
    list1.append(five)
    list1.append(six)
    list1.append(seven)
    list1.append(eight)
    list1.append(nine)
    list1.append(ten)
    list1.append(eleven)
    list1.append(twelve)
    print(list1)
    
    
def dice_roll():
    diceRoll = random.randint(1, 6)
    return diceRoll

main()
```

My goal here is now to create a list outside the loop, that accumulates the values of each game anyone wants to play.
In the end I want a list, that stores the values for each index (two eyes, three eyes, four eyes.... etc ... twelve eyes) in one list.

The Output right now looks like this:

```
how many rounds?  999
two = 27  three= 56  four= 84  five= 114  six= 142  seven= 175  eight= 112  nine= 120  ten= 83  eleven= 54  twelve= 32
[27, 56, 84, 114, 142, 175, 112, 120, 83, 54, 32]
```

Thats fine so far, what I want now is to make it possible, that anyone can play several games and then have all the data stored in one list.
How can I manage that task?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can save the data in a file, and load it the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1**: How to store data

The classic data structure for this kind of problem is a dictionary. You can use it to accumulate a counter of values.

```py
# Creating an empty dictionary
my_dict = {}

# Storing/updating values in a dictionary
my_dict[key] = some_value

# Retrieving the value from a dictionary
print(my_dict[key])
>>> some_value
```

```py
# initialise the dictionary with the desired values
counter = {key: 0 for key in range(2:13)}

while rounds <= int(player_input):
    # Just repeating your rolling code here
    roll1 = dice_roll()
    roll2 = dice_roll()
    third = roll1 + roll2    

    # Incrementing the counter
    counter[third] += 1

# Will print out the key, value pairs in the dictionary
print(counter)
```

**Part 2**: How to continuously loop:

The logic here is that you need two loops. One loop keeps asking for player input, and the other loop actually plays the game for the results.

```py
# setup the dictionary
counter = {key: 0 for key in range(2, 13)}

# outer loop will keep asking for user input
while True:
    try:
        rounds = int(input('How many rounds do you want to roll the dice?'))
    except TypeError:
        # handle invalid input, going to break for now
        print('Invalid input, exiting')
        break
    
    # Handles a 0 input as an exit instruction
    if rounds == 0:
        break

    # loops and rolls the dice
    for _ in range(rounds):
        # Just repeating your rolling code here
        roll1 = dice_roll()
        roll2 = dice_roll()
        third = roll1 + roll2    

        # Incrementing the counter
        counter[third] += 1
```

At the end, the dict will accumulate the results of all rolls over multiple rounds of user input.

Comment: and how is this getting out of the loop?

Comment: would there be another solution? With lists?

Comment: Updated solution. The use of lists is doable but dicts represent the idea of association more strongly. In this case, you are *associating* a result (key) with the number of times it showed up (value).

Answer (score 0):

Okay the Dictionary Version works with the Dictionary as the Data Storage. But a new question arises: How can I get back to the while loop and the input function.

I want the user to be able to play as many games as he/she wants and always come back to the question: "how many rounds (throws) ?".

The output from all that games I want to store in one single dictionary.

I just want to understand how this can work with python?
And later on I want to use the Data for statistical analyses and visualisation like normal distribution etc.

And pls. i don't want the "easy" solution with mathplot etc. I want as basic as it can get to understand and learn about the process with the most primitive python that is possible.

What u have now, due to the Dictionary advice:

```
import random

player_input = input("how many rounds? ")





def main():
    roll1 = 0
    roll2 = 0 
    rounds = 1
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0 
    six = 0
    seven = 0
    eight = 0
    nine = 0
    ten = 0
    eleven = 0
    twelve = 0
    list1 = []
    my_dict = {}


    while rounds <= int(player_input):
        roll1 = dice_roll()
        roll2 = dice_roll()
        third = roll1 + roll2
        
        
        
        
        if third == 2:
            two = two + 1
            
        
        elif third == 3:
            three = three + 1
            
        
        elif third == 4:
            four = four + 1
    
        
        elif third == 5:
            five = five + 1
        
        elif third == 6:
            six = six + 1
         
        elif third == 7:
            seven = seven + 1        
        
        elif third == 8:
            eight = eight + 1
            
        elif third == 9:
            nine = nine + 1
            
        elif third == 10:
            ten = ten + 1
            
        elif third == 11:
            eleven = eleven + 1
            
        elif third == 12:
            twelve = twelve + 1
            
        rounds = rounds + 1
    print("two =", + two, " three=", + three, " four=", + four, " five=", + five, " six=", + six, " seven=", + seven,
              " eight=", + eight, " nine=", + nine, " ten=", + ten, " eleven=", + eleven, " twelve=", + twelve)
        
       
            
        
    new = {0: int(two), 1: int(three), 2: int(four), 3: int(five), 4: int(six), 5: int(seven), 6: int(eight), 
           7: int(nine), 8: int(ten), 9: int(eleven), 10: int(twelve)} 
    my_dict.update(new) 
     


    print(my_dict)


def dice_roll():
    diceRoll = random.randint(1, 6)
    return diceRoll

main()
```

How can I now repeat the same game over and over (as long as wanted) and store the data outside the loop in the dictionary?

Thanks a lot Folks!

Comment: your use of `two, three, four` etc. is unnecessary btw. The dictionary is your storage, you don't need these other variables.